# C++ msgpack std::map with variadic type keys

Tags: c++, msgpack

I have an object that has entries like this (lua):

```
{1, 2, 3, four=4}
```

And I want to iterate over the entries. How can I perform that? I tried this:

```
auto map = arg.as<std::map<msgpack::object, msgpack::object>>();

for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {

    auto obj = it->second;
}
```

but seems not to be compiled. Do you have any clues about it?

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?